# RadComboBox CheckBoxes mulitselect get values of CheckedItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have master page named MPHome.master contains a RadComboBox here is the code of

```
<telerik:RadComboBox CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" ID="TaskID" runat="server" Height="100" Width="150" EmptyMessage="Select a Task"
EnableLoadOnDemand="true" OnClientItemsRequesting="OnClientItemsRequesting"    WebServiceSettings-UseHttpGet="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="true"  EnableVirtualScrolling="true">
        <WebServiceSettings Method="GetTasks" Path="~/ProjectDropDownWebService.asmx"   />
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Now this combo works fine it fills values from webservice and also shows checkboxes on it.Now what I do is I inherit this master page to Default.aspx page and inside button of submit in default page I have used this code

```
 protected void btnViewAllTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         RadComboBox TaskID = (RadComboBox)Master.FindControl("TaskID");
    var selectedtask = TaskID.CheckedItems;
}
```

This selectedtask returns me count of zero either i have selected all the records on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. You are trying to use the CheckBoxes along with Load On Demand feature which is not a supported scenario with telerik RadComboBox with checkboxes=true.

Please find more details about this topic [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-usability-checkboxes.html).